# Making sure Identity column doesn't allow change in another value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an identity column known as RowId which is needed. However, I have an issue where I am seeing multiple instances of that same RowID 5-10 times where the customerNumber changes and that should not be allowed. For instance:

```
  RowID:                   CustomerNumber:
  2556892                  25231564656522
  2556892                  25232264686453
```

How can I make sure my table does not allow the CustomerNumber to change? The point of having an identity column is to have different RowId's when a value is added such as a new CustomerNumber. Somehow instead of the new CustomerNumber getting a new rowId it is being modified and they are changing the CustomerNumber. How can this be prevented?

Comment: I find it hard to believe is the RowID column really set to identity in the database.  Can you double check that?  an Identity column by definition can't have the same value. My guess is the identity property isn't set to true.

Comment: The only way you'd get duplicates in an IDENTITY column would be disable any unique constraints/primary keys that might cover it, to set `IDENTITY INSERT` to ON and *manually* insert duplicate values.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos or a RESEED instead of IDENTITY INSERT

Comment: A month ago you were trying to implement versioning to your customer table. At that time it did not have an identity column. If this is the same table (or related one), perhaps your versioning logic is faulty?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a new table for customers:

```
create table Customers as (
    CustomerId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    CustomerNumber varchar(20) unique -- or whatever
    -- add more columns about customers
);
```

Voila!  You have only one `CustomerId` per `CustomerNumber`.  This is appropriate for foreign key relationships.  You can then remove `CustomerNumber` from your current table, rename `rowid` to `CustomerId` (which is more descriptive), and define an appropriate foreign key relationship.